# Replacing array elements using regex and replace() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, str-replace

I'm bit new to JavaScript, I'm trying to replacing the array element using regex that matches the string, here is a code which I tried

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">ClickHere</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var abc = ["deno", "eno","pqr","lenovo"];
    var i,text;
    for(i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
        text += abc[i].replace(/no/i, "po");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to replace array element with "po" wherever it encounters "no" in the array element string.

This is what I expect:

```
abc["depo","epo","pqr","lepovo"]
```

Comment: Expect array or string in output ? You have a typo as `,` in loop..https://jsfiddle.net/pkjsdu9w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for every element:

```
for(var i=0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    abc[i] = abc[i].replace('no', 'po');
}
```

or using one line

```
abc = abc.map(function(x){return x.replace('no', 'po');});
```

or using one line with "arrow functions":

```
abc = abc.map(x => x.replace('no', 'po'));
```

After you changed the array, you can convert it to a string using:

```
var text = 'abc['; 

for ( var i = 0 ; i < abc.length ; i++ ) {
    text+='\"'+abc[i]+'\"';
    if ( i != abc.length - 1) {
        text+=',';
    }
}
text += ']';
```

#### Test:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var abc = ["deno", "eno","pqr","lenovo"];
    abc = abc.map(x => x.replace('no', 'po')); // see other 2 alternatives above

    var text = 'abc['; 

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < abc.length ; i++ ) {
        text+='\"'+abc[i]+'\"';
        if ( i != abc.length - 1) {
            text+=',';
        }
    }
    text += ']';
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ClickHere</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: After using your first solution ,its giving me this output                                    denodepo,enoepo,pqrpqr,lenovolepovo                                                       which I think its taking the element first printing and then doing the replacement

Comment: @deepesh , I added the conversion to text, where I don't use `replace` anymore, because I've already changed the array. You can also see a snippet integrating all those parts. Click on Run code snippet to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i, text;
for(i = 0; i < abc.length, i++) {
  text += abc[i].replace("no", "po");
}
  console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three changes required in your code:

1. Initialiize text with empty string.Because it is undefined by default.
2. Change abc[i].length to abc.length.
3. Replace comma with a semicolon after abc[i].length  in for loop.

   ```
   var abc = ["deno", "eno","pqr","lenovo"];
   var i;
   var text = "";
   for(i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
      text += abc[i].replace("no", "po");
   }
   ```

Comment: To your solution this is the answer I got                                                          depoepopqrlepovo

Comment: I tried using "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text + "<br>"; " to break line but it didnt gave the desired result